# Which Python 3 API to get started?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Programming experience with C, C++ and Java and in the last week I learned Python 3 with the **official tutorial** and **A Byte of Python**. I want to start programming in Python, and my ideas for the first projects are either a browser-based simple blog-software (just login & poste - **nothing more** to keep it simple) or a simple RSS FeedReader with an GUI.

But it looks like every Project is still using Py2 instead of Py3: Django and other Web Frameworks as well as GUI-Toolkits.
I only find Tk (which look&feel is really bad, imo) and GObject. Because I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and don't want to install a non-stable Gnome3-PPA, I can't use GObject.

**Is there any good Py3 Framework for web or gui based programming?** Or can I do my simple blog-software with the standard library, in an appropriate time? If yes: Can anyone give me a tutorial? Nothing found yet, still all tutorials based on Django or something else Py2 related.

Answer (score 4):

[PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) supports python 3.

Comment: Oh thank you, didn't noticed that.
I couldn't find a tutorial for it on the official page, but I googled and found http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/
Does anyone know another good tutorial for PyQt?

Comment: @quantez, API of PyQt is very similar to those of Qt itself so C++ documentation is usually used. I don't know about tutorials since I came to PyQt from C++/Qt background, but there is a book "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt".

Answer (score 3):

[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) runs on Python 2.3 and above (yep Python 3 as well.)

It is quite easy to get into as well, which might align with your stated goals of simplicity. It won't provide you with a templating engine or ORM though like Django. But this can be obtained separately, for example [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html).